# jquery hide() and slideDown()

Tags: jquery, show-hide, slidedown

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#AddCity').hide();
 $('#AddCityA').click(function(){
     if ( AddCityVar==1 ){
         $('#AddCity').hide();
         var AddCityVar=0;
     }else{
           $('#AddCity').slideDown("slow");
           var AddCityVar=1;
     }
  });
```

I cant figure this out, why div with ID #AddCity is opening on first click on #AddCityA link, but never goes hide on second click? Does $('#AddCityA').click(function() work only once?

```
<a href="#" id="AddCityA">Add City</a> 

<div id="AddCity">
    here some code
</div>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be re-initialisng `AddCityVar` everytime you assign some value to it. You need to have it outside the scope of the click function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#AddCity').hide();
    var AddCityVar= 0;
    $('#AddCityA').click(function(){
      if ( AddCityVar==1 ) {
         $('#AddCity').hide();
         AddCityVar=0;
      }
      else {
         $('#AddCity').slideDown("slow");
         AddCityVar=1;
      }
    });
 });
```

But, as roasted mentioned, it neednt have a variable to do this. You can just use `slideToggle` :

```
$('#AddCityA').click(function () {
  $('#AddCity').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

A Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/9cdKL/

Comment: +1 but AddCityVar doesn't need to be in global scope, btw in your example, it isn't

Comment: @passionateCoder thank u very much! yeah, this one is working

Comment: @user2437063 : glad to help . if u think this has helped u, be sure to mark it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You could just check if the element is visible:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#AddCity').hide();
    $('#AddCityA').click(function () {
        var state = $('#AddCity').is(':visible');
        $('#AddCity')[state?'hide':'slideDown'](state ? 0 : 'slow');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KGs5n/2/)

For a much simpler approach, you could slide the element both ways :

```
    $('#AddCity').hide();
    $('#AddCityA').on('click', function () {
        $('#AddCity').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: I wish i can vote this up. this one is also working well. Thank u